# How to interpret file content as template string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I was wondering if there was a way to use the content read from a file as a template string?

Ex: my file hello_world.txt :

```
hello world from ${name}
```

And then something like (with nodejs) :

```
var name = 'Jérémie';
var fileContent = fs.readFileSync('./hello_world.txt');
debug(fileContent); // Hello word from Jérémie
```

It seems possible, using the eval() function, but I don't really like this solution.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably look into a real template library if you want something like this. I like [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/), as it's pretty light and easy to use.

Comment: @ssube I'm already using mustache, your solution would be to use it instead of a template string?

Comment: @apsillers yeah I saw this thread, but not sure I was really the target :-/

Comment: @Gnujeremie if you're loading a string (not code) from a file, you have to either treat it as a mustache template or as code. Mustache will have better error handling and generally be safer than `eval`.

Comment: Why was this marked as a duplicate? The linked thread didn't deal at ALL with reading files and writing them after interpolating their content.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you trust the files you are reading, you can accomplish this with `eval`:

```js
let message = "${greeting} World",
    greeting = "Hello";
    
alert(eval(`\`${message}\``))
```

Comment: As I said in my question, I know it is possible using eval() but I was looking for a solution without the eval() function.